# Needassistance Debugging " Data element already Been set" error on IBM ILOG CPLEX studio

Tags: optimization, cplex, mixed-integer-programming, docplex

I have made a model to optimize FPL team selection and tried running for 3 rounds of the season. However I am getting an error for the data set "Pq" which is the set of players p allowed to play in position q and is indexed by the set Q.

The error message is " data element 'Pq' has already been set". I am also getting a processing failed error.

This set is present in the data file below.

Could someone please help?
Thanks

.Mod File -

```
t//SETS
{string} P = ...; //Set of all players
{string} Q = ...; // Set of all positions
int Rounds = ...; // number of rounds


{string} Pq[Q]; // Set of all players p in P who are allowed to play in position q in Q
//{string} Qp[P]; // Set of all positions q in Q, where player p in P is allowed to play
range R = 1..Rounds;

// PARAMETERS
float points[P][R]; // points of player p in round R
float price[P][R]; // Price of player p in round R
float B = ...; // Budget
int C_min[Q]; // min Available spots of Postion Q
int C_max[Q]; // Max available spots of Position Q
int X[R] = ...; // Number of players whose scores count towards team score in each round
int T_total = ...; // max number of trades that can be used
int T[R] = ...; // trades per round


//DECISION VARIABLES
dvar boolean x[P][R]; // If player p is in team for round r
dvar boolean y[P][R]; // If the score of player p is included in round r
dvar boolean C[P][R]; // If player p is captain for round r
dvar boolean t_in[P][R]; // If player p is traded into the team for round r (r > 1)
dvar boolean t_out[P][R]; // If player p is traded out of the team for round r (r > 1)
dvar float+ b[R]; // Remaining budget at round r

 //12.1 OBJECTIVE FN
 
maximize sum(p in P, r in R) (points[p][r] * (y[p][r] + 2*C[p][r]));  


// CONSTRAINTS

subject to{
// 12.2 trade constraint per season
  forall(p in P, r in R: r > 1) 
    t_in[p][r] <= T_total;
    
// 12.3 Limiting the number of trades per round
  forall(r in R) 
    sum(p in P) t_in[p][r] <= T[r];  
    
// 12.4 update of  trades per round -> Q removed as each player can only play one postions
  forall (p in P, r in R: r > 1) 
      x[p][r] - x[p][r-1] ==  t_in[p][r] - t_out[p][r];
   
     
// 12.5 Captain selection  
   forall (r in R) 
    sum(p in P) C[p][r] == 1;
        
//12.6 captain position selection -> removed Q as again, all positions assumed scoring
   forall(r in R, p in P) 
      x[p][r] >= C[p][r];
                
// 12.7 Max available spots of each position
    forall (r in R, q in Q) 
    sum(p in Pq[q]) x[p][r] <= C_max[q];
  
 // 12.7a Min available spots of each position  
  forall (r in R, q in Q)   
    sum(p in Pq[q]) x[p][r] >= C_min[q];
  
    
//12.9 player has to be in scoring position for score to be counted
 forall(p in P, r in R) 
    y[p][r] ==  x[p][r];
  
  
// 12.10 No of players whose scores count towards team score in each round  
  forall(r in R) 
    sum(p in P) y[p][r] == X[r]; 
    
    
// 12.11 Value of initial side + Remaining budget <= Budget
    b[1] + sum(p in P) price[p][1] * x[p][1] == B;
  
// 12.12 remaining budget calculation
  forall(r in R:r>1) 
    b[r] == b[r-1] + sum(p in P) price[p][r] * t_out[p][r] - sum(p in P) price[p][r] * t_in[p][r];
  
}
```

```
Data file -

//SETS

// set of players p
P = {"Trippier","White","Schar", "Mings","Van Dijk", "Shaw", "Saliba",
      "Raya", "Alisson", "De Gea","Pope", "Sa",
      "Haaland", "Watkins", "Wilson", "Jesus", "Mitrovic", "Firmino",
      "De Bruyne","Salah", "Rashford", "Martinelli", "Almiron", "Trossard","Eze", "Son"};

// set of postions q
Q = {"GK", "DEF", "MID", "FWD"}; 

**// indexed by q, set of players p allowed to play in Q position
Pq = {{"Raya", "Alisson", "De Gea", "Pope", "Sa"},
      {"Trippier", "White", "Schar", "Mings", "Van Dijk", "Shaw", "Saliba"},
      {"De Bruyne", "Salah", "Rashford", "Martinelli", "Almiron", "Trossard", "Eze", "Son"},
      {"Haaland", "Watkins", "Wilson", "Jesus", "Mitrovic", "Firmino"}
     };**


Rounds = 3;
X = 11; // Number of players whose scores count towards team score in each round
T = 1; // trades per round


// PARAMETERS

// points scored by player p in P in round r in R
points = [
     [7, 7, 6], [5, 1, 7], [15, 5, 0], [0, 2, 1], [1, 2, 1], [0, -1, 0], [8, -1, 14], 
     [1, 2, 1], [1, 2, 1], [1, 1, 3], [6, 10, 3], [2, 15, 3],
     [13, -1, 6], [1, 11, 6], [6, 2, 6], [2, 19, 4], [13, -1, 6], [1, 0, 2],
     [6, 14, 5], [12, 2, 8], [2, 1, 10], [8, 8, 6], [3, 3, 7], [1, 3, 8], [2, 6, 3], [5, 2, 3]
   ];  
   
 // The price of player p in P in round r in R
price = [
    [5.0, 5.0, 5.0], [4.5, 4.5, 4.5], [4.5, 4.6, 4.6], [4.5, 4.5, 4.4], [6.5, 6.5, 6.5], [5.0, 5.0, 4.9], [4.5, 4.5, 4.5],
    [4.5, 4.5, 4.5], [5.5, 5.5, 5.5], [5.0, 5.0, 4.9], [5.0, 5.0, 5.0], [5.0, 5.0, 5.0],
    [11.5, 11.6, 11.7], [7.5, 7.4, 7.4], [7.5, 7.5, 7.5], [8.0, 8.0, 8.1], [6.5, 6.6, 6.6], [8.0, 8.0, 8.0],
    [12.0, 12.0, 12.1], [13.0, 13.0, 13.0], [6.5, 6.5, 6.3], [6.0, 6.1, 6.3], [5.0, 5.0, 5.0], [6.5, 6.5, 6.5], [5.5, 5.5, 5.5], [12.0, 12.0, 11.9]
      ]; 

// 100 million
B = 100.0;

//  min number of available spots (capacity) of position q in Q
C_min = {1,3,3,1}; 
C_max = {1,5,5,3};

// Total transfers over season.
T_total = 3;
```

I need this code to run so that i can proceed with attaching excel sheet data for all the players in the premier league.

I am doing this for my maste's thesis and any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, when your values are defined in the .dat you should use ... in the .mod

For instance you should write

```
{string} Pq[Q]=...; // Set of all players p in P who are allowed to play in position q in Q
//{string} Qp[P]; // Set of all positions q in Q, where player p in P is allowed to play
range R = 1..Rounds;

// PARAMETERS
float points[P][R]=...; // points of player p in round R
float price[P][R]=...; // Price of player p in round R
float B = ...; // Budget
int C_min[Q]=...; // min Available spots of Postion Q
int C_max[Q]=...; // Max available spots of Position Q
int X[R] = ...; // Number of players whose scores count towards team score in each round
int T_total = ...; // max number of trades that can be used
int T[R] = ...; // trades per round
```

Second, you mix [ and { in your .dat

I would rather write

```
// set of players p
P = {"Trippier","White","Schar", "Mings","Van Dijk", "Shaw", "Saliba",
      "Raya", "Alisson", "De Gea","Pope", "Sa",
      "Haaland", "Watkins", "Wilson", "Jesus", "Mitrovic", "Firmino",
      "De Bruyne","Salah", "Rashford", "Martinelli", "Almiron", "Trossard","Eze", "Son"};

// set of postions q
Q = {"GK", "DEF", "MID", "FWD"}; 
Pq = [{"Raya", "Alisson", "De Gea", "Pope", "Sa"},
      {"Trippier", "White", "Schar", "Mings", "Van Dijk", "Shaw", "Saliba"},
      {"De Bruyne", "Salah", "Rashford", "Martinelli", "Almiron", "Trossard", "Eze", "Son"},
      {"Haaland", "Watkins", "Wilson", "Jesus", "Mitrovic", "Firmino"}
     ];


Rounds = 3;
X = [11]; // Number of players whose scores count towards team score in each round
T = [1]; // trades per round


// PARAMETERS

// points scored by player p in P in round r in R
points = [
     [7, 7, 6], [5, 1, 7], [15, 5, 0], [0, 2, 1], [1, 2, 1], [0, -1, 0], [8, -1, 14], 
     [1, 2, 1], [1, 2, 1], [1, 1, 3], [6, 10, 3], [2, 15, 3],
     [13, -1, 6], [1, 11, 6], [6, 2, 6], [2, 19, 4], [13, -1, 6], [1, 0, 2],
     [6, 14, 5], [12, 2, 8], [2, 1, 10], [8, 8, 6], [3, 3, 7], [1, 3, 8], [2, 6, 3], [5, 2, 3]
   ];  
   
 // The price of player p in P in round r in R
price = [
    [5.0, 5.0, 5.0], [4.5, 4.5, 4.5], [4.5, 4.6, 4.6], [4.5, 4.5, 4.4], [6.5, 6.5, 6.5], [5.0, 5.0, 4.9], [4.5, 4.5, 4.5],
    [4.5, 4.5, 4.5], [5.5, 5.5, 5.5], [5.0, 5.0, 4.9], [5.0, 5.0, 5.0], [5.0, 5.0, 5.0],
    [11.5, 11.6, 11.7], [7.5, 7.4, 7.4], [7.5, 7.5, 7.5], [8.0, 8.0, 8.1], [6.5, 6.6, 6.6], [8.0, 8.0, 8.0],
    [12.0, 12.0, 12.1], [13.0, 13.0, 13.0], [6.5, 6.5, 6.3], [6.0, 6.1, 6.3], [5.0, 5.0, 5.0], [6.5, 6.5, 6.5], [5.5, 5.5, 5.5], [12.0, 12.0, 11.9]
      ]; 

// 100 million
B = 100.0;

//  min number of available spots (capacity) of position q in Q
C_min = [1,3,3,1]; 
C_max = [1,5,5,3];

// Total transfers over season.
T_total = 3;
```

Comment: Thank you Alex for your time. It is running now!
I am new to CPLEX and not very good at understanding the Errors. I just had one more doubt. Once this model ran, It left me with 26 warnings.
All were the same with different players. An example -

Decision Variable "t_out["Alisson"][1]" has never been used by the engine

Is this an issue or I can ignore this?

Thanks Again!